# Delete string(1) " "

Tags: php, foreach

I get from a from a list:

```
one     "\n"
        "\n"
two     "\n"
```

I do an explode when I get the list:

```
     $list_explode_nl = explode("\n", $list);
```

var_dump shows:

array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "one " [1]=> string(1) " " [2]=> string(4) "two" }

My code:

```
  foreach ($list_explode_nl as $k => $v) {
     if ($v == NULL || $v == ' ') {
        unset($list_explode_nl[$k]);
     }
  }
```

I want to get rid of an element, when the string is like [1]. How?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach ($list_explode_nl as $k => $v) {
    if ($v == NULL || trim($v) == '') {
        unset($list_explode_nl[$k]);
    }
 }
```

I think the `[1]` element is a newline (or possibly tab) so it will not equal `' '`.  [trim](http://php.net/trim) should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$list_explode_nl = array_filter(array_map('trim',$list_explode_nl));
```

or

```
$list_explode_nl = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim',$list_explode_nl)));
```

if you want to reset the indexes as well